# How to load and read yml fixture files for rspec in ruby

Tags: ruby

## frozen_string_literal: true

require 'yaml'
require 'singleton'

module OrionTechCurrencyPlugin
  module Rules
    class RulesLoader
      include Singleton

```
  PATH = '**/data/**/*.yml'

  def initialize
    @rule = load
  end

  def fetch(key)
    @rule[key]
  end

  private

  def load
    hash_def = {}
    files = Dir[PATH]

    files.each do |file_name|
      definition = YAML.load_file(file_name).deep_symbolize_keys
      Hash.merge!(definition)
    end
    hash_def
  end
end
```

end
end

This is the class i have. I Want to write specs for this class. Earlier i had mocked the load methos but now i want to use fixtures to store the mock data and load and read from those files.

yml files are stored in the folder structure as shown below.
data
--test
test.yml
test2.yml
test3.yml

the fixture folder and files are as shown below
specs
--main
  --fixtures 
    test.yml
    test1.yml

Comment: Maybe add some yaml files in the test dir and change the definition of `PATH` temporily, or alternatively pass the path as an argument to the method. Would be better if you showed what you tried, question is really vague right now.

Comment: I have edited the question and added some more code to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

First, it is rather unclear if this method is defined in `controller` or `model`, let us look at how it is to be done for both. I am assuming that you're using `rails` framework as you're using method `deep_symbolize_keys`

1. Define your `PATH` variable inside environment files for all `development`, `test` and `production` environment. In `development` & `production` `env` it would be the path to your `yml_files` whereas in `test` this would be the path to your fixtures files i.e `spec/fixtures/files/*` which is default location for fixture files to reside.
2. Now for your `model` method rspec would look like this:

   ```
   # spec/models/some_model_spec.rb

   require 'rails_helper'
   RSpec.describe SomeModel, type: :model do
     describe '#load' do
       it 'reads sample.yml file and convert to hash' do
         some_model = SomeModel.new
         expect(article.load).to eq(expected)
       end
     end
   end

   def expected
     {
       "person": {
         "name": "Chandler Bing",
         "profession": "Inputting Numbers",
         "aim": "SO",
         "address": {
           "street": "21 Jump Street",
           "city": "Manhattan"
         }
       }
     }
   end
   ```

`some_model` object can be put into a `before` block if there are multiple specs.

Now for your `controller` method (I'd make an assumption that it `render`s `hash` as `json` object) it would be something like this:

```
# spec/controllers/some_controller_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe ArticlesController, type: :controller do
  describe '#load.json' do
    it 'reads sample.yml file and convert to hash' do
      get :load

      expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to eq(expected)
    end
  end
end

def expected
  {
    "person"=> {
      "name"=> "Chandler Bing",
      "profession"=> "Inputting Numbers",
      "aim"=> "SO",
      "address"=> {
        "street"=> "21 Jump Street",
        "city"=> "Manhattan"
      }
    }
  }
end
```

For a sample.yml file

```
# spec/fixtures/files/sample.yml
person:
  name: Chandler Bing
  profession: Inputting Numbers
  aim: SO
  address:
    street: 21 Jump Street
    city: Manhattan
```